# ASP .NET Core gives System.Net.Sockets.SocketException error on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, .net-core

I am trying to deploy .NET core web API to Heroku.

Below is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY /out ./
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet dotnetcoreapi.dll
```

This `Dockerfile` works fine on Heroku, but when I tried to deploy with

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY /out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","dotnetcoreapi.dll"]
```

Heroku gives me this error:

> Unable to start Kestrel. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied

Why doesn't `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","dotnetcoreapi.dll"]` work on Heroku? Both versions work fine on my local machine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've just solved this problem thanks to Chis' answer and [this blogpost](https://habr.com/en/post/450904/).

It turns out that Heroku really wants to take care of the ports for you (probably for security reasons).

With boilerplate asp core template, with docker suport added you start with:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TestWebApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj", "TestWebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestWebApp"
RUN dotnet build "TestWebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestWebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestWebApp.dll"]
```

Heroku expects your app to run on the port Heroku gives you in `PORT` environment variable. It'll expose 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) ports for you. So what you have to do is:

Remove these lines form your `Dockerfile`:

```
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Then you have to make your application listen on that port. To make it work, you have to change your `Program.cs` file:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");

                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseUrls("http://*:" + port);
                });
```

Then Heroku does it's magic and your app still gets HTTPS support.

### Hint:

The default Dockerfile won't work out of the box with Heroku CLI. The generated Dockerfile is supposed to be ran from the solution level (not project level). I was unable to force heroku CLI to use a Dockerfile form a nested direcotry. The way I made id work was:

1. Go to your **solution** directory
2. Create Dockerfile
3. Paste modified content:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj", "TestWebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj"
COPY ./TestWebApp ./TestWebApp
WORKDIR "/src/TestWebApp"
RUN dotnet build "TestWebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestWebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestWebApp.dll"]
```

4. `heroku login`
5. `heroku container:login`
6. `heroku container:push web --app your-app & heroku container:release web --app your-app`

Comment: Neatly explained. :)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! The Program.cs changes are a little different now as this answer seems to be for .NET Core 3.1. For .NET 6, I had to do the following in my Program.cs file. Pardon the formatting, comments aren't full markdown.

`WebApplicationBuilder? builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

WebApplication? app = builder.Build();
string? port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port)) {
 app.Urls.Add("http://*:" + port);
}
`

Comment: You're a life saver my man, thanks for the explanation too. I have literally no idea what im doing with docker and I just needed the site to work on heroku. Changing the program.cs file did the trick.

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks!  I was deploying .netcore 6.0 app and did not need to do what @Duu82 suggested

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't really about your `ENTRYPOINT`, but rather the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable that you use with `CMD`:

```
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet dotnetcoreapi.dll
```

Here you run your application setting `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to a single URL using the `PORT` given to you by Heroku.

In the second `Dockerfile`, you don't provide that environment variable and you get a socket error. It's very likely that your application is trying to listen for both HTTP and HTTPS (or maybe just HTTPS) connections.

Heroku provides a *single* port for you to use, and your application should listen for HTTP (not HTTPS) connections on that Port. Heroku will take care of the HTTPS part.

Try this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY /out ./

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:$PORT
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","dotnetcoreapi.dll"]
```